# SQL Standard between two values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering, is there a difference in SQL Standard or in MySQL when we use 'between'.
To be more precise In SQL Standard if I do :

```
A between 1 and 10
```

Is it equal to :

```
1 <= A and A <= 10
-- or
1 < A ans 1 < 10
```

Is the result the same in MySQL.

Comment: `1 <= A` and `A <= 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [mysql dev doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

> expr BETWEEN min AND max
>
> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal
>   to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. This is equivalent
>   to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments
>   are of the same type. Otherwise type conversion takes place according
>   to the rules described in Section 12.2, “Type Conversion in Expression
>   Evaluation”, but applied to all the three arguments.

It clearly states that **A between 1 and 10** will be equal to **1 <= A and A <= 10**

Answer (score 0):

**In MySQL**

Let "employee_tbl" table contains employee name, daily_typing_pages columns.

```js
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-04-06 |                100 |
|    4 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-06-06 |                300 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-02-06 |                350 |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

If we run the following query on this table:

```
SELECT * FROM employee_tbl 
WHERE daily_typing_pages BETWEEN 170 AND 300;
```

the query results the following output:

```js
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    4 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-06-06 |                300 |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

That means between works as an inclusive. It results the data including 170 and 300.

**In MSSQL**

Let "Products" table contains product data including product name, price etc.

```js
ProductID ProductName                         Price
1         Chais                          18
2         Chang                          19
3         Aniseed Syrup                  10
5         Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix          21.35
4         Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning            22
```

If we run the following query on this table:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Price BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

The query results the following data including the prices given in between clause.

```js
ProductID ProductName          Price
1         Chais           18
2         Chang           19
3         Aniseed Syrup   10
```

So in MSSQL between works as an inclusive as like as MySQL.

you can have a look on this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm

and this

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp